# Using HttpClient with SOAP

Tags: c#, soap, httpclient

I have been trying to use the HTTPClient object in .Net Framework 4.7 to create a simple SOAP request. I have used the parameters in Postman and it works perfectly fine. Here's my code:

```
 string url = "http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso";

        //SOAP envelope string
        string xmlSOAP =
           @"<? xml version = ""1.0"" encoding = ""utf-8"" ?>
           < soap : Envelope xmlns: soap = ""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" >
                < soap:Body >
                    < ListOfContinentsByName xmlns = ""http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo"">         
                    </ ListOfContinentsByName >
                </ soap:Body >
           </ soap:Envelope >";

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(xmlSOAP);
        HttpResponseMessage response;

        HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "");
        req.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        req.Content = httpContent;
        req.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/xml; charset=utf-8");

        // Here you will get the Reponse from service
        response = await httpClient.SendAsync(req);
        // Converting the response into text format
        var responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Any idea why this works in postman but not using the HTTPClient? I referenced this from the microsoft example here (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/15e0c692-c47c-443c-b96d-5c4f77e7ed66/how-to-sendreceive-soap-request-and-response-using-c-in-windows-phone-8?forum=wpdevelop).

Comment: Did I answer the question?

Answer (score 13):

Your code looks fine and should work. Looks like the API server is down now.

Here's the same code with few fixes and improvements that just makes it stable

```csharp
public class Program
{
    private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso";

        string xmlSOAP = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
            <soap:Body>
            <ListOfContinentsByName xmlns=""http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo""/>         
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>";

        try
        {
            string result = await PostSOAPRequestAsync(url, xmlSOAP);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task<string> PostSOAPRequestAsync(string url, string text)
    {
        using (HttpContent content = new StringContent(text, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"))
        using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
        {
            request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "");
            request.Content = content;
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            {
                //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // throws an Exception if 404, 500, etc.
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Probably you may additionally fill `SOAPAction` e.g. with `url`, but it depends on server requirements.

Comment: Thanks for this. `SOAPAction` was the crucial bit I was missing.