# Send soap request with keystore file using HttpClient or other C# class

Tags: c#, httpclient

I have a client that helped us to configure a SOAP API using Ready-API tool. They used Keystore file as WS-Security config,

[image]

Now, how can I use HttpClient class or any other .NET class to send the same request using C#?

Comment: Do you have a WSDL with a description of the service?

Comment: You can create the XM portion with any XML Net Library.  Then add headers to a HTTP Request and put the xml as the contents of the http.

Comment: [Some samples here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62995629/12888024)

Comment: How can I attach keystore file?

Comment: I just needed to convert keystore to p12 and set client certificate `var _clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler(); _clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert); _clientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;`